# FLASK на сервере запускается многократно

Tags: python, flask

При запуске на сервере приложения Flask оно запускается одновременно несколько раз.

В коде Flask установлено `app.run(debug=False, use_reloader=False)`.
При запуске на удаленном сервере app.run все работает как надо. Но при запуске с помощью `sudo supervisorctl start name` приложение запускается 4 раза, при этом каждый раз инициализируясь.

Помогите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть дело?

Comment: 1 - как вы определили, что запустилось 4 раза? 2 - почему вы видите в этом проблему?

Comment: 1. Любая функция, исполнение которой я добавляю в код, выполняется при запуске приложения 4 раза.
2. Нет возможности разово выполнить какую-либо функцию.

Comment: Добавьте пример кода в вопрос. Сейчас не понятно, что у вас за функции там выполняются.

Comment: @insolor Кажется, тут дело не в коде Python, а в процессах на самом сервере. Абсолютно любой код, добавленный в приложение, исполняется многократно, хоть print(), хоть другие функции. Похоже, сервер запускает приложение параллельно несколько раз. Причем при некоторых запусках было 2 повторения, при некоторых 3. Сейчас - 4. Сервер на Linux, возможно, есть какой-то способ продиагностировать, что происходит?

Comment: Вы просто добавили исполняемый код на "верхнем" уровне (вне функций или методов), или отнаследовались от Flask, и в `__init__` что-то выполняете?

Comment: Например, я использую apscheduler для запуска повторяющегося процесса. Следующий код добавлен на верхнем уровне:
`sched = BackgroundScheduler(daemon=True)
sched.add_job(update_db, 'interval', hours=24, start_date='2021-04-17 11:30:00')
sched.start()`
При старте приложения запускается 4 экземпляра этой задачи. То есть, в заданное время она выполняется 4 раза.

Comment: Посмотрите ответы к этому вопросу, возможно что-то подойдет: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27465533/4752653